# Getting error tb_sales_person_source.id is invalid in the select list in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, I have below query which is working fine in Mysql server, but it is not working in SQL Server, I get an error:

> tb_sales_person_source.id is invalid in the select list

Can anyone please help me how can I resolve this error ?

```
SELECT 
    tb_sales_person_source.id,
    tb_sales_person_source.name,
    tb_sales_person_source.display_name, 
    tb_sales_person_source.mapped_sales_person_source_id,
    tb_sales_person_source.company_id, 
    tb_sales_person_source.gm_created,
    tb_sales_person_source.gm_modified,
    COUNT(tb_Episode.id) AS total_soc, 
    SOCDate, MonthSOC
FROM 
    tb_Episode
JOIN 
    tb_sales_person_source ON tb_sales_person_source.id = tb_Episode.sales_referral_source_id
WHERE 
    (BranchID = '238' OR BranchID = '239' OR BranchID = '240' OR BranchID = '241')
    AND tb_Episode.CustID = '27'
    AND PayerType = 'Ep'
    AND SOC = 1
    AND SOCDate >= '2016-04-01'
    AND SOCDate < '2017-5-01'
GROUP BY 
    sales_referral_source_id, MonthSOC
ORDER BY 
    tb_sales_person_source.id ASC, tb_Episode.SOCDate ASC;
```

Comment: In SQL server, you must have to add all the columns of "SELECT" in "Group by" apart from the column which is used in the aggregate function

Comment: I used that but i am not getting same data as it works in mysql server

Comment: Share the sample data with expected result so we can help you

Comment: I want to group by data by MonthSOC column

Comment: Please update your query so that ***all*** the column names in your query have a table name with them.  Am I meant to ***guess*** if, for example, `BranchID` comes from the sales person table, or from the episode table?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL server, you must have to add all the columns of "SELECT" in "Group by" apart from the column which is used in the aggregate function

```
SELECT tb_sales_person_source.id
    ,tb_sales_person_source.NAME
    ,tb_sales_person_source.display_name
    ,tb_sales_person_source.mapped_sales_person_source_id
    ,tb_sales_person_source.company_id
    ,tb_sales_person_source.gm_created
    ,tb_sales_person_source.gm_modified
    ,count(tb_Episode.id) AS total_soc
    ,SOCDate
    ,MonthSOC
FROM tb_Episode
JOIN tb_sales_person_source ON tb_sales_person_source.id = tb_Episode.sales_referral_source_id
WHERE (
        BranchID = '238'
        OR BranchID = '239'
        OR BranchID = '240'
        OR BranchID = '241'
        )
    AND tb_Episode.CustID = '27'
    AND PayerType = 'Ep'
    AND SOC = 1
    AND SOCDate >= '2016-04-01'
    AND SOCDate < '2017-5-01'
GROUP BY sales_referral_source_id
    ,MonthSOC
    ,tb_sales_person_source.id
    ,tb_sales_person_source.NAME
    ,tb_sales_person_source.display_name
    ,tb_sales_person_source.mapped_sales_person_source_id
    ,tb_sales_person_source.company_id
    ,tb_sales_person_source.gm_created
    ,tb_sales_person_source.gm_modified
    ,SOCDate
ORDER BY tb_sales_person_source.id ASC
    ,tb_Episode.SOCDate ASC
```

Comment: I don't want to use all the cloumns in group by, I want to group by with MonthSOC column

Comment: @Nikul Panchal, understood. But when you group by using MonthSOC, other column data like "NAME" , "gm_created" are the same or it have different value?

Comment: It can be have different value

Comment: Then logically, you have to add all in group by

Comment: I added it, but it is not match with mysql data

Comment: It would be good if you share the sample data and expected output

Comment: @NikulPanchal - MySQL and SQL Server behave differently.  SQL Server behaves more like MySQL when this mode is on *(which is the default from version 5.7 onwards)* : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to accurately re-write your query until you update it to make it clear which table each column comes from.

The important piece of information you need to be aware of, however, is that when using `GROUP BY` ***every*** field in the `SELECT` must either have an aggregate function around it *(`MIN()`, or `MAX()`, or `SUM()`, etc, etc)*, or be mentioned in the `GROUP BY`.

This means that the following is NOT valid SQL...

```
SELECT
  t1.some_id,
  t1.name,
  t1.whatever,
  COUNT(t2.id),
  SUM(t2.value)
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
    ON t2.some_id = t1.some_id
GROUP BY
  t1.some_id
```

Instead you need one of the following...

```
SELECT
  t1.some_id ,
  t1.name,
  t1.whatever,
  COUNT(t2.id),
  SUM(t2.value)
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
    ON t2.some_id = t1.some_id
GROUP BY
  t1.some_id,
  t1.name,
  t1.whatever
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  t1.some_id,
  MAX(t1.name),
  MAX(t1.whatever),
  COUNT(t2.id),
  SUM(t2.value)
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
    ON t2.some_id = t1.some_id
GROUP BY
  t1.some_id
```

The same is true even if you are grouping by a column from table 2.

So, this is invalid too...

```
SELECT
  t1.some_id,
  t1.name,
  t2.a_date,
  COUNT(t2.id),
  SUM(t2.value)
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
    ON t2.some_id = t1.some_id
GROUP BY
  t2.a_date
```

This time, however, you have an extra option.  Use a sub-query to group up the data in table 2 first...

```
SELECT
  t1.some_id,
  t1.name,
  t2_agg.a_date,
  t2_agg.count_rows,
  t2_agg.total_value
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    some_id,
    a_date,
    COUNT(t2.id)    AS count_rows,
    SUM(t2.value)   AS total_value
  FROM
    t2
  GROUP BY
    some_id,
    a_date
)
  t2_agg
    ON t2_agg.some_id = t1.some_id
```

If you fully qualify your query *(so I can see which table **every** column comes from)* then I can show you how to use this method to suit your exact case.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i resolved my query, here is my query, thanks to all of you for your help

```
SELECT tb_sales_person_source.id, tb_sales_person_source.name, tb_sales_person_source.display_name, count(tb_Episode.id) as total_soc, MonthSOC
FROM tb_Episode
JOIN tb_sales_person_source ON tb_sales_person_source.id = tb_Episode.sales_referral_source_id
WHERE ( BranchID = '238' or BranchID = '239' or BranchID = '240' or BranchID = '241')
AND tb_Episode.CustID =  '27'
AND PayerType =  'Ep'
AND SOC =  1
AND SOCDate >= '2016-04-01'
AND SOCDate < '2017-5-01'
GROUP BY tb_sales_person_source.id, tb_sales_person_source.name, tb_sales_person_source.display_name, sales_referral_source_id, MonthSOC
ORDER BY tb_sales_person_source.id asc
```